# How do I set the options for a programatically created content type?

Tags: nodes

For example, if I want to set 'Publishing options - Promoted to front page' to 0 in a .install file when creating a new content type.

I've looked in the variable table, where I was expecting to see variables for these options, but it's not obvious to me. What am I supposed to set?

Thanks.

Comment: One way to check would be to download a copy of the Features module and quickly make a feature of a content type (on a backup site).  Then you could check what variables Features adds to the feature module.

Comment: Similar question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17118/when-creating-a-content-type-programmatically-is-there-a-way-to-disable-promoti

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `node_options_[type]` variable,

e.g:

```
node_options_article: Array
(
    [0] => status
    [1] => promote
)
```

which can be set with:

```
// Make my_type nodes published and not promoted to front page by default
variable_set('node_options_my_type', array('status'));
```

Comment: Thanks. So variable_set will create node_options_my_type in the variable table. And the exclusion of 'promote' in the array passed to varaible_set will set it to false and the inclusion of 'status' sets it to true, correct?

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the case.